# PHP Header Expires for Dynamic Content

Tags: php, header

By using following command my resource files are getting cached till 15 Apr 2014

```
header('Expires: Thu, 15 Apr 2014 20:00:00 GMT');
```

How to handle the situation if any resource file is getting changed before the expiry date?

Comment: Simple; don't send that header if there's any chance the content will change between now and then.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the chances of change are rare, in that case we can't omit the advantage of caching.

Comment: @Wyzard's answer is the right one -- adding something to the URL, like a version id (e.g., `?v=1`) and/or using last-modified headers is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no way to tell the client that its cached copy is no longer valid, because it doesn't need to even request this URL again from your server until that date.

What you *can* do, if you really need to, is change the URL of the resource ­— e.g. rename the file, change a database ID, whatever.  Of course, you'll also have to update any links to the resource.  When the the client encounters one of the modified links, it'll see a URL that it *doesn't* have cached, so it'll have to request it from the server.  (If there's any chance that someone might still try to access the old URL, you should arrange for it to return a 301 Moved Permanently response that points to the new URL.)

Unless you're sure that the resource won't change again (or at least that the client won't need to see any future changes) before that date, you should stop sending the far-future Expires header.  If you're trying to avoid having the client repeatedly download a large resource, you can send an ETag and/or Last-Modified header instead.  Those allow the client to use If-None-Match and/or If-Modified-Since in future requests, so you can send 304 Not Modified if the resource hasn't changed.  That way you can have the client *check* with the server every time, but only actually *download* the resource when it changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to use ETag as I never used before.

Answer (score 0):

for example you have a css file that`s name is "style.css"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
```

and now you changed this css content and you want to refresh this file in user`s browser

only you should add a string to this css url like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css?1" />
```

i added '?1' to this file`s url.
then user`s browser thing this url is new and it will fetch this file again